# Can you replace fields from query with fields from a split query in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a report in Power BI that cannot refresh because the data from the table is too large:

> The amount of data on the gateway client has exceeded the limit for a single table. Please consider reducing the use of highly repetitive strings values through normalized keys, removing unused columns, or upgrading to Power BI Premium

I have tried to shrink the columns used in the data set to the best of my ability, but it is still too large to refresh. I did a test where, instead of using just a single query to retrieve the data, I made two queries that split the columns roughly half and half and then link them back together in Power BI using their ID column. It looked to me that the test data refresh started working upon splitting up the table's data into two separate queries.

Please correct me if there is a better method to trim the data down to allow the data set to refresh, but for now this is the best solution I see. What I am wondering is, since now my data is split into two separate queries, **what is the best way to adapt the already existing visualizations I have that are linked up to the full, non-refreshable query to the split, refreshable queries?** It looks to me like I would have to recreate the visuals from scratch, but if there is a way to simply do a mass replace of the fields that would save so much time. The split queries I created both have the same fields as the non-split query.

Comment: The most likely solution to your problem (assuming you are using a data source that supports query folding) would be implementing [incremental refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview) and potentially even doing additional reading regarding [partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview) and how that might interact with your incremental refresh strategy. There are also other space saving methods that can be used with tabular models. The two table approach is not a good solution.

Comment: Thank you, the incremental refresh was exactly what I needed given my data set. The initial refresh upon deployment almost timed out, but subsequent refreshes were much shorter and were successful.